# Codeigniter 3 blog bug: post id is replaced with category id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a basic **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8.

The posts are diaplayed on the homepage and also filtered *by categories*.

Whenever I try to view a post *from a category page* its url has the *category id* at the end, *instead of the post id*. All post in the category with id 1 link to `http://localhost/ciblog/posts/post/1`.

In the **Posts_model** model there is:

```
public function get_posts_by_category($id, $limit, $offset) {
    $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = posts.cat_id');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('cat_id' => $id));
    return $query->result();
}
```

In the **Categories** controller:

```
public function posts($id) {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = [
        'base_url' => base_url('/categories/posts/' . $id),
        'page_query_string' => TRUE,
        'query_string_segment' => 'page',
        'display_pages' => TRUE,
        'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
        'per_page' => 12,
        'total_rows' => $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows_by_category($id),
        //More code
    ];
    if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
        $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
    }
    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['category_name'] = $this->Categories_model->get_category($id)->name;
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts_by_category($id, $limit, $offset);

    $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('categories/posts');
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
}
```

The posts view in the above controller:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1 class="display-4 category-name"><?php echo $category_name; ?></h1>
    </div>  
    <?php if ($posts): ?>
        <div class="posts-grid">
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post) :?>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="post">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url('posts/post/') . $post->id; ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/posts/') . $post->post_image; ?>" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <h2 class="card-title">
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url('posts/post/') . $post->id; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $post->title; ?>
                                </a>
                            </h2>
                            <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $post->description; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="read-more">
                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success" href="<?php echo base_url('posts/post/') . $post->id; ?>">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="text-muted" id="no_posts">There are no posts in the <?php echo $category_name; ?> category yet.</p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $this->load->view("partials/pagination");?>

</div>
```

The posts images, titles, etc are displayed correctly. **Not** the links to the single post...

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the select portion in your query by using `$this->db->select();`.

**Alternative:**

```
public function get_posts_by_category($id, $limit, $offset) {
    $this->db->select('posts.*'); // added
    $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = posts.cat_id');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('cat_id' => $id));
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: I worked. I am puzzled though: why was *the rest* of the post correctly rendered?

Comment: In theory, without the `select()` call, the return columns default to all columns (via *) from the  two tables defined - posts and categories. Since posts and categories have the same column named `id` the second table overwrites that of the first table - hence you get id = 1 on all posts - which is the category id. You still get records to render either way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to SELECT the table where you are retrieving the data your Post_module should look like:

```
public function get_posts_by_category($id, $limit, $offset) {
    $this->db->select('t1.*');
    $this->db->order_by('t1.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->join('categories t2', 't2.id = t1.cat_id');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts t1', array('t1.cat_id' => $id));
    return $query->result();
}
```